# How to get ONLY A PART of Json for my ViewHolder? (in Kotlin)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-viewholder

I'm using a recyclerView and having trouble being able to get only a part of my api call(json) into my ViewHolder. I tried using subString(), get(), but was not able to do it.

This is my viewHolder :

```
holder.fighterRanking.text = rankingData.competitorRankings.toString()
```

And this is my Json , Note: I have reached the maximum character limit here so the Json below is about 30% of the full thing, it has several more objects that are "lightweight", "featherweight", etc..  ,**I want ONLY the "name" and "rank" from each "heavyweight" in my view holder**:

```
"generated_at": "2020-05-21T10:35:49+00:00",
    "rankings": [
        {
            "type_id": 13,
            "name": "welterweight",
            "year": 2020,
            "week": 21,
            "competitor_rankings": [
                {
                    "rank": 0,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:273539",
                        "name": "Usman, Kamaru",
                        "abbreviation": "USM"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 1,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:274653",
                        "name": "Woodley, Tyron",
                        "abbreviation": "WOO"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 2,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:265079",
                        "name": "Covington, Colby",
                        "abbreviation": "COV"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 3,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:260633",
                        "name": "Masvidal, Jorge",
                        "abbreviation": "MAS"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 4,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:256121",
                        "name": "Edwards, Leon",
                        "abbreviation": "EDW"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 5,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:265063",
                        "name": "Thompson, Stephen",
                        "abbreviation": "THO"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 6,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:267851",
                        "name": "Burns, Gilbert",
                        "abbreviation": "BUR"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 7,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237670",
                        "name": "Maia, Demian",
                        "abbreviation": "MAI"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 8,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237628",
                        "name": "Chiesa, Michael",
                        "abbreviation": "CHI"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 9,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237634",
                        "name": "Dos Anjos, Rafael",
                        "abbreviation": "DOS"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 10,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237632",
                        "name": "Diaz, Nate",
                        "abbreviation": "DIA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 11,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:413419",
                        "name": "Neal, Geoffrey",
                        "abbreviation": "NEA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 12,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237666",
                        "name": "Lawler, Robbie",
                        "abbreviation": "LAW"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 13,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:267863",
                        "name": "Luque, Vicente",
                        "abbreviation": "LUQ"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 14,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237676",
                        "name": "McGregor, Conor",
                        "abbreviation": "MCG"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 15,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:253389",
                        "name": "Pettis, Anthony",
                        "abbreviation": "PET"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type_id": 14,
            "name": "middleweight",
            "year": 2020,
            "week": 21,
            "competitor_rankings": [
                {
                    "rank": 0,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:410485",
                        "name": "Adesanya, Israel",
                        "abbreviation": "ADE"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 1,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:253377",
                        "name": "Whittaker, Robert",
                        "abbreviation": "WHI"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 2,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:320689",
                        "name": "Costa, Paulo Henrique",
                        "abbreviation": "COS"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 3,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:250133",
                        "name": "Cannonier, Jared",
                        "abbreviation": "CAN"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 4,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237704",
                        "name": "Romero, Yoel",
                        "abbreviation": "ROM"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 4,
                    "movement": 1,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:338797",
                        "name": "Till, Darren",
                        "abbreviation": "TIL"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 6,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:278283",
                        "name": "Hermansson, Jack",
                        "abbreviation": "HER"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 7,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:268061",
                        "name": "Gastelum, Kelvin",
                        "abbreviation": "GAS"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 8,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:244098",
                        "name": "Brunson, Derek",
                        "abbreviation": "BRU"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 9,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:462119",
                        "name": "Shahbazyan, Edmen",
                        "abbreviation": "SHA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 10,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:257353",
                        "name": "Hall, Uriah",
                        "abbreviation": "HAL"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 11,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:284469",
                        "name": "Tavares, Brad",
                        "abbreviation": "TAV"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 12,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:541995",
                        "name": "Akhmedov, Omari",
                        "abbreviation": "AKH"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 13,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:465483",
                        "name": "Heinisch, Ian",
                        "abbreviation": "HEI"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 14,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:248585",
                        "name": "Carlos Junior, Antonio",
                        "abbreviation": "CAJ"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 15,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:245465",
                        "name": "Jotko, Krzysztof",
                        "abbreviation": "JOT"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type_id": 15,
            "name": "light_heavyweight",
            "year": 2020,
            "week": 21,
            "competitor_rankings": [
                {
                    "rank": 0,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:253371",
                        "name": "Jones, Jon",
                        "abbreviation": "JON"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 1,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:347406",
                        "name": "Reyes, Dominick",
                        "abbreviation": "REY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 2,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237712",
                        "name": "Santos, Thiago",
                        "abbreviation": "SAN"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 3,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:250143",
                        "name": "Blachowicz, Jan",
                        "abbreviation": "BLA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 4,
                    "movement": 1,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:246017",
                        "name": "Anderson, Corey",
                        "abbreviation": "AND"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 5,
                    "movement": 3,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:250881",
                        "name": "Teixeira, Glover",
                        "abbreviation": "TEI"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 6,
                    "movement": -2,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:244765",
                        "name": "Smith, Anthony",
                        "abbreviation": "SMI"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 7,
                    "movement": -1,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542115",
                        "name": "Oezdemir, Volkan",
                        "abbreviation": "OEZ"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 8,
                    "movement": -1,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:278293",
                        "name": "Gustafsson, Alexander",
                        "abbreviation": "GUS"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 9,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:372544",
                        "name": "Rakic, Aleksandar",
                        "abbreviation": "RAK"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 10,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:256105",
                        "name": "Krylov, Nikita",
                        "abbreviation": "KRY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 11,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:511852",
                        "name": "Walker, Johnny",
                        "abbreviation": "WAL"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 12,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:265089",
                        "name": "Cirkunov, Misha",
                        "abbreviation": "CIR"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 13,
                    "movement": 1,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:449135",
                        "name": "Spann, Ryan",
                        "abbreviation": "SPA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 14,
                    "movement": -1,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:419867",
                        "name": "Ankalaev, Magomed",
                        "abbreviation": "ANK"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 15,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:257355",
                        "name": "Rua, Mauricio",
                        "abbreviation": "RUA"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type_id": 16,
            "name": "heavyweight",
            "year": 2020,
            "week": 21,
            "competitor_rankings": [
                {
                    "rank": 0,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237684",
                        "name": "Miocic, Stipe",
                        "abbreviation": "MIO"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 1,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:253373",
                        "name": "Cormier, Daniel",
                        "abbreviation": "COR"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 2,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:250145",
                        "name": "Ngannou, Francis",
                        "abbreviation": "NGA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 3,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542009",
                        "name": "Blaydes, Curtis",
                        "abbreviation": "BLA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 4,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237636",
                        "name": "Dos Santos, Junior",
                        "abbreviation": "DOS"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 4,
                    "movement": 1,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542099",
                        "name": "Lewis, Derrick",
                        "abbreviation": "LEW"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 6,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542143",
                        "name": "Rozenstruik, Jairzinho",
                        "abbreviation": "ROZ"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 7,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542161",
                        "name": "Volkov, Alexander",
                        "abbreviation": "VOL"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 8,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:237694",
                        "name": "Overeem, Alistair",
                        "abbreviation": "OVE"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 9,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:254231",
                        "name": "Harris, Walt",
                        "abbreviation": "HAR"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 10,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542117",
                        "name": "Oleinik, Aleksei",
                        "abbreviation": "OLE"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 11,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:244080",
                        "name": "Abdurakhimov, Shamil",
                        "abbreviation": "ABD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 12,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542079",
                        "name": "Ivanov, Blagoy",
                        "abbreviation": "IVA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 13,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:542145",
                        "name": "Sakai, Augusto",
                        "abbreviation": "SAK"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 14,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:515358",
                        "name": "Pavlovich, Sergey",
                        "abbreviation": "PAV"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "rank": 15,
                    "movement": 0,
                    "competitor": {
                        "id": "sr:competitor:257349",
                        "name": "Werdum, Fabricio",
                        "abbreviation": "WER"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

If anybody could point me in the right direction or just flat out help me out, I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Do you use something like `Gson, Moshi or Jackson` for handling json data? If yes its better you also add  your `Model` and more code of adapter

Comment: I use Gson, I was gonna add more to my post but it was too many characters and I have to delete. 
I used Retrofit with GsonConvertorFactory and have a model as well. I Api call works fine but I just want the specific object from the json.

Comment: Post your model code

Comment: I need to see how you have mapped those objects

Comment: Model code:
`data class Rankings(
    @SerializedName("rankings")
    val rankings: List<Ranking>
)
data class Ranking(
    @SerializedName("competitor_rankings")
    val competitorRankings: List<CompetitorRanking>,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("type_id")
    val typeId: Int,
    @SerializedName("week")
    val week: Int,
    @SerializedName("year")
    val year: Int
)
`

Comment: Model code: 
`data class Ranking(
    @SerializedName("competitor_rankings")
    val competitorRankings: List<CompetitorRanking>,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("type_id")
    val typeId: Int,
    @SerializedName("week")
    val week: Int,
    @SerializedName("year")
    val year: Int
)
data class Rankings(
    @SerializedName("rankings")
    val rankings: List<Ranking>
)`

Comment: Those are 4 data classes, My Api call works fine, I just don't know how to get back only a small part of the json instead of the entire thing..

Comment: I am trying to use json you posted to genarate kotlin data classes via https://www.json2kotlin.com/ but it seems invalid. I wish the code above would be properly formatted and added in question instead. So just paste proper json. And if you wrote those data classes by hand I would suggest using data class generators

Comment: Yes, I used the Json to Kotlin Data Class plugin in Android Studio.  I had to delete half of my json from this post because it was too many characters and it couldn't fit in the post. Can I message you the full Jason object?

Comment: Now I have seen what is going wrong, why dont you add adapter code so that I can point it directly

Comment: `class RankingsAdapter(private val ranking: List<Ranking>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RankingsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.heavyweight_rankings_row,parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun getItemCount() = ranking.size`

Comment: `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val rankingData = ranking[position]
        holder.fighterRanking.text = rankingData.competitorRankings.toString()

    }
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val fighterRanking: TextView = itemView.fighter_ranking

    }

}`

Comment: There it is, I had to share it in two parts because it had too many characters for one post

Comment: Its hard to read code posted via comment. I suggest that you update your question by pasting them there